# Brain tumor reconstruction as 3D mesh via 2D MRI scans in Python

Tags: image-processing, multidimensional-array, 3d, python-3.5, point-clouds

My program takes [2D Brain-MRI Voxels](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BxJXjT3AXXHlZG9KQUhpR1BlWG8?usp=sharing) as an input, from a top down view of a brain, and my goal is to create a 3D model from the MRIs of JUST the tumors.

I've been able to apply a thresholding function which contrasts the MRI images, making the cancer [significantly more visible](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BxJXjT3AXXHlWWVFTkw1S0lDMjQ?usp=sharing) (cancer becomes pure black and the rest of the brain becomes pure white).

Now comes the hard part - I'd like to use edge detection to create a point cloud of JUST the cancer in each slice of the MRI, and then create a mesh from the collective point clouds of each slice, to model the cancer in three dimensions.

The MRIs I'm working with are centred in the XY plane and simply extrude upwards along the Z axis as they scan upwards through the brain, I think I can make a series of 2D point clouds for each image, and then "stack" the point clouds evenly across the Z axis, with a consistent Z distance between each slice.

Does that sound doable in a month? Any recommendations of a streamlined way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any particular reason you want to use a point cloud? Constructing a surface mesh from point clouds can be a colossal headache, especially if you're dealing with a voxel-based volume representation in the first place. The usual approach when dealing with medical imaging (and voxel data in general) is to use something like the [Marching Cubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes) algorithm on the voxel volume of interest to create a polygonal surface mesh.

So as a general approach, I'd recommend first constructing the 3D voxel volume of the tumor(s). To do this, traverse the slices and create somekind of 3D array of values based on your pixel contrast threshold in the slice. Once you have your voxel volume, you can use the marching cubes/tets algorithm to get a nice smooth mesh of the volume. I spared the details but hopefully you get the idea.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Dnkrtz, the images I'm using are JPG format, because I'm not sure how to process DICOM images (I don't really have the skill or time). What I'm planning on doing is letting the user of this program input the dimensions of the skull, and then based on the number of images the program runs, the z-height of each image will simply divide the height of the skull by the number of images, and thus I will be able to stack the (x,y) coordinates of the tumors at a consistent z interval. Hope this makes sense. Given the properties of the images I'm using, can you suggest a new method to do this?

Comment: Dean, what you've just described will be how you create the voxel volume (you're effectively assigning a height to each pixel of each slice, making it a voxel with a color value). Once you have that stored as an array, you can segment the tumor based on the color threshold you described, and use marching cubes on the tumor voxel volume. Does that help?

Comment: Ah ok, Yes, it does! Thank you! I actually decided that I'll probably use Open CV's blob detection, and set the thresholds to only detect segments of the image which resemble tumors (large enough, right pixel value, not perfectly circular, etc.). I'll pull the general shape of the tumors out of each image that way, and then I can build up the voxel volume. Will try your marching cubes suggestion too.